# How to handle import loops in Sass?

Tags: sass

I have a main sass file named index.sass that defines some global variables such as colors and style the body, and a TitleBar.sass that style the title bar.

*index.sass:*

```
@use './TitleBar'

$primaryColor: blue

body:
  box-sizing: border-box
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  padding-top: $titleBarHeight
  overflow: auto
```

*TitleBar.sass*

```
@use './index'

$titleBarHeight: 32px
  
.titleBar
  position: fixed
  top: 0
  left: 0
  box-sizing: border-box
  width: 100%
  height: $titleBarHeight
  background: $primaryColor
```

The issue is that I want to use $primaryColor which is defined in index.sass in TitleBar.sass and I want to use $titleBarHeight which is defined in TitleBar.sass in index.sass. To do so I have to import them into each other, but if I do that I have a loop import error. Is there a way to achieve that or should I define $titleBarHeight in index.sass?

Comment: It's possible with [Interoperable CSS](https://github.com/css-modules/icss), but I only tried on SCSS and I'm not sure about SASS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you need to break the loop manually by splitting the code up into different files.

I found it a good rule-of-thumb to define *local* sass/scss variables for things that are never intended to be used outside the respective component-style; but to move all variables that are likely to affect other styles into dedicated *constants* files.
Your `$titleBarHeight` and `$primaryColor` both are of the latter category.

To illustrate this:

```
// index.sass
@import './page-layout'
@import './title-bar'
```

```
// page-layout.sass
@use './colors'
@use './dimensions'

body:
  box-sizing: border-box
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  padding-top: $titleBarHeight
  overflow: auto
```

```
// title-bar.sass
@use './colors'
@use './dimensions'

$nav-item-gap: 8px // only for local use
  
.titleBar
  position: fixed
  top: 0
  left: 0
  box-sizing: border-box
  width: 100%
  height: $titleBarHeight
  background: $primaryColor

.navContainer
  display: flex
  gap: $nav-item-gap
```

```
// colors.sass
$primaryColor: blue
$secondaryColor: pink
// etc.
```

```
// dimensions.sass
$titleBarHeight: 32px
$pageFooterHeight: 16px
$pageGutter: 64px
// etc.
```